# how find unique value from Different column

Tags: excel

```
A   B     ANSWER
1   1   1
3   3   3
1   2   1
2   4   2
4   4   4
5   5   5
6   6   6
```

i have used this function to get above answer "=IF(ISERROR(MATCH(A2:A8,$B$1:$B$8,0)),"",A2)"

but I need answer like this i have given below (suppose if you take value in A column "1"
Which is repeated only once in column B)

```
A   B        ANR
1   1   1
3   3   3
1   2   0
2   4   2
4   4   4
5   5   5
6   6   6
```

Answer (score 0):

I've just wrapped your formula in a condition that returns `0` where the count of the `A` value from start to the current row is more than one:

```
=IF(COUNTIF(A$1:A2,A2)>1,0,IF(ISERROR(MATCH(A2:A8,$B$1:$B$8,0)),"",A2))
```

.

---

An alternative formula that gives the same results as above for the sample data provided but may (or may not) suit the additional requirements mentioned in a comment:

```
=IF(COUNTIF(A$2:A$10,A2)<=COUNTIF(B$2:B$10,A2),A2,IF(COUNTIF(A$2:A2,A2)>COUNTIF(B$2:B$10,A2),0,IF(COUNTIF(A$2:A$10,A2)>COUNTIF(B$2:B2,A2),A2,0)))
```

Comment: thank you for your respounds if a value column A '1' is repeating 5 Times in same column and coulum B '1' is repeating 4 times in column B Then Column A '1' meats 4 times with Column B'1'so the balance will be  1 time in column A '1' should be '0'